# jQuery hover multiple blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm using jQuery hover function to hover over the `box-empty` class. On the hover, it replaces the `box-empty` to `box-full`.

1. On hover over a block, how can I hover over all previous blocks too?
2. When clicking on the block, how can I add the class `box-full` to all previous blocks?

**Edit:**
Sorry, I forgot to mention that I need to include the block which has been clicked/hover also (not only the previous ones).

[image]

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap"> 
    <span class="box box-empty"></span>
    <span class="box box-empty"></span>
    <span class="box box-empty"></span>
    <span class="box box-empty"></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.box-empty').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('box-full');
        $(this).removeClass('box-empty'); 
    }, function () {
        $(this).addClass('box-empty');
        $(this).removeClass('box-full');
    });
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/aCP9x/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `prevAll()`. You will also need `addBack()` to include the element currently being hovered over. Try this:

```
$('.box-empty').hover(function () {
    $(this).prevAll().addBack().toggleClass('box-full box-empty');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/aCP9x/3/)

Note I also simplified your code by using `toggleClass`, which means the same function can run on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` within the `hover`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and also for improving my code. Sorry, I forgot to mention, I need to include the div which has been clicked/hover also (not only the previous ones).

Comment: @user1251698 that's what it should be doing. Is it not working for you?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That is what it is doing. I [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/FxJrL/)ed the fiddle to make it so that the bar keeps it's state when the mouse leaves. Not what the OP asked for, but probably what he wants.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I just replaced addBack with andSelf.@DanRoss Thank you very much too, yes, thats what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @user1251698 glad you got it working, although you should note that `andSelf()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 in favour of `addBack()`: http://api.jquery.com/andself/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just tried that, but there's some funky behavior going on. I can make a 0101 pattern by mousing around.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that too.

Answer (score 3):

A pure CSS aproach:

```
span:hover ~ span, span:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #000;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/TfyaR/1/)

As mentioned by Fabrício Matté below, you can take advantage of the CSS checkbox hack, allowing you to effectively toggled between selected/unselected.

Comment: OP wanted only those to the left of that hovered to be highlighted, I don't think that's possibly in CSS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I was able to figure it out: http://jsfiddle.net/TfyaR/ .. just can't do anything about the clicking functions in CSS, so it's useless.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Awesome - completely forgot about the checkbox hack. You should put that as an answer.

Comment: Nah it's a bit too hackish (cluttered HTML, no IE<9 support), the JS solution is probably more maintainable. Feel free to use the fiddle. `=]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.box').hover(
    function () {
        $('.box:lt(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').toggleClass('box-full box-empty'); 
    }, 
    function () {
        $('.box:lt(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').toggleClass('box-empty box-full');
}
);
```